# How to study Maths for ML

Tags: machine-learning

I have started Machine Learning but I am not sure up to what extent should I study its Maths part and also
from where to study it. I am more interested in Machine Learning's application part building models and not in algorithm derivation. So I need suggestion for how much Maths should I study and that too from where?

Comment: Start by not studying math, and see if you understand (the application side) and you can apply. If you don't, focus on those parts' math.